# How to display page4 on one page if clicked 'next'

Tags: html

I have a page, if I click `about` on that page then I would like view `page2` in `other` page.

In `other` page, there is consist 5 page. but if I click `about`, then page1 will displayed, not directly showing page2. please help

here my code:

```
<ul class="sf-menu">
   <li class="current men"><a href="#">Adverb</a> <strong class="hover"></strong></li>
   <li class="men1"><a onClick="goToByScroll('page1'); return false;" href="#">Home</a><strong class="hover"></strong></li>
   <li class=" men2"><a onClick="goToByScroll('page2'); return false;" href="#">About</a> <strong class="hover"></strong></li>
   <li class=" men3"><a onClick="goToByScroll('page3'); return false;" href="#">Services</a> <strong class="hover"></strong></li>
   <li class=" men4"><a onClick="goToByScroll('page4'); return false;" href="#">Contact</a> <strong class="hover"></strong></li>
   <li class=" men5"><a onClick="goToByScroll('page5'); return false;" href="#">Login</a> <strong class="hover"></strong></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: from which page the result is wroing ?

Comment: can you make a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/)?